# NSFetchedResultsController and UITableView Sections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate a `UITableView`, and would like to know if it is possible to create different sections based on an attribute of my data model.

I am displaying a table of objects, and one of the properties of the objects is a BOOL that is set to indicate whether or not the object is active.  I would like to break the records apart in the `UITableView` and have section one display the objects with Active==YES and the second section display objects that are not active.

How is this done?

Answer (score 4):

You set the `sectionNameKeyPath:` of the NSFetchedResultController initialization method to the name of the attribute you want to use for the sections. The FRC returns a section for each unique value of that attribute.